# Getrect() within callback function is having runtime errors

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using a slider to show a new image from a cell array of images. Basically, the callback function of the slider displays the i-th image in the cell array if the value of the slider is 'i'.

Within that callback function, I am trying to allow the user to select a rectangle using the mouse. The MATLAB [getrect()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getrect.html) method is used to do that - it is not working within the callback:

```
Reference to a cleared variable GETRECT_H1.

Error in getrect (line 121)
elseif (~ishghandle(GETRECT_H1) || ...

Error in faceSliderGUI/slider_callback (line 23)
        rect = getrect(gca);

Error using waitfor
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Reference to a cleared variable GETRECT_H1.
```

The callback function is as shown below:

```
%# Callback function
    function slider_callback(hObj, eventdata)
        value = round(get(hObj,'Value')); 
        imageHandle = imshow(image_series{value});
        ah = get( imageHandle, 'Parent' );
        rect = getrect(ah); %let user draw a rectangle with mouse
        set(hTxt, 'String',num2str(value))       %# update text
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `imrect` instead of `getrect`.